# JAVA cannot see added components to panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, repaint

Task: Delete several controls from panel, then add new ones.

Problem: after completing several methods, old controls disappear, but I cannot see new ones.

code:

```
    public void StartGame() {
    ActionPanel.removeAll();
    CreateOponentField();
    ActionPanel.repaint();

}
    private void CreateOponentField() {
    ActionPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(10, 10));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            LabelArray[i][j] = new JLabel();
            LabelArray[i][j].setOpaque(true);
            LabelArray[i][j].setBackground(BattleShipEnumClass.ColorMap.get(GridCellState.EMPTY));
            LabelArray[i][j].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

            ActionPanel.add(LabelArray[i][j]);
```

}}}

May someone know where is problem/mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ActionPanel` is an instance of `JComponent`, you can use:

```
ActionPanel.revalidate();
```

Otherwise

```
ActionPanel.invalidate();
ActionPanel.validate();
```

Comment: revalidate() & repaint(), invalidate() is properly implemented in APIs, could be important for Custom LayoutManager